# jQuery added form elements cannot be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I apologise for the description if it's not fitting. It was hard to describe what's going on.

I have set up a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/wvepd6ge/).

```
function addNewForm() {
    $('body').html(function () { //display log in form
        return "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Word or Phrase\" id=\"prompt\" />\n" +
            "<textarea id=\"answer\" placeholder=\"Answer text\"></textarea>\n" +
            "<input type=\"button\" id=\"addnew\" value=\"Add This!\" />\n" +
            "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
    });
}

$("#addnew").click(function () {
    $("p").html("ADD NEW CLICKED<br />");
});

$("a").click(function () {
    addNewForm();
});
```

Is my syntax correct? For some reason, `$("#addnew").click` works when generated outside of its own function but the button stops working since I have tidied my code and placed it within its own function. Is there a reason that jQuery may not recognise an element that has been created through a function?

Cheers!

Comment: I added the '#' in the anchor tag. Works fine now: https://jsfiddle.net/wvepd6ge/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wvepd6ge/2/   event.preventDefault() is what you needed

Comment: That fixed the jsFiddle error, but it did not get `$("#addnew").click` to work. But I do thank you for getting rid of the jsFiddle error!

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio now when I click the add button it just adds a repeat of the form on the bottom. What is causing that?? Shouldn't it just add the text in the `$("#addnew").click` function?

Comment: yes, last fiddle was showing the form appended to your A element. this stops adding more forms: https://jsfiddle.net/wvepd6ge/5/

Comment: although it still fails to change the content of P when #addnew is clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is here :

https://jsfiddle.net/wvepd6ge/7/

When you add your button, you need to attach the event like this :

```
function addNewClicked() {
    $('.result').html("ADD NEW CLICKED<br/>");
}

$("a").click(function () {
    addNewForm();
    $("#addnew").click(function () {
        addNewClicked();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check your link, I don't think you saved the changes. But I tested them and it worked. Thank you.This is very interesting. Is this a form of scope?

Comment: $('.result').html("ADD NEW CLICKED<br/>");   this is not working.

Comment: neither is the next console.log()

Comment: MowgliB - It is not really a form of scope. But you can't bind a click event to an element that doesn't exist. In you're example you were binding the click event to the #addnew element on page load. But that element didn't exist until you clicked the link. By Binding the Click event to the #addNew element after running the addNewForm() function you're sure that the #addNew element exists when the binding is applied. that's why jquery uses the $(document).ready(function(){. Because you can't bind to elements that have not yet been loaded to the DOM.

Comment: "It is not really a form of scope." I withdraw my words :x Sry

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to attach an `onclick` event handler onto `#addnew`, the element doesn't exist at that time.
You need to attach it when you add the form into DOM or use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

```
$(document).on("click", "#addnew", function () {
    $("p").html("ADD NEW CLICKED<br />");
});
```

You would probably also like to prevent the page from reloading, when you click the `<a>` link

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addNewForm();
});
```

Fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rb6koog/